# jboss-deployment-structure.xml add JAXP exclusion

Tags: java, xml, spring, jboss, jaxp

I am implementing XML validation which prevents XXE (External XML Entity) Injection. I borrowed some code from [OWASP XXE Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XML_External_Entity_(XXE)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet). My code looks like this -

```
        SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        Schema schema = factory.newSchema(xsdFileURL);
        Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
        validator.setProperty(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, "");
        validator.setProperty(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_SCHEMA, "");
        validator.validate(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xml)));
```

The code runs correctly on my local windows machine (JDK 1.8.0_92, Wildfly 8.2). But on a QA Red Hat machine with similar config (JDK - 1.8.0_101, Wildfly 8.2), it throws an **exception** with the message -

```
Property 'http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD' is not recognized.
```

After some reading my suspicion is that during runtime, incorrect class definition is being read for the `validator` class. How do I fix this?

**Update**

Turns out Jboss comes with its own implementation of `JAXP`, and my code needs to pick the JAXP implementation from JDK and not from JBoss. I can do this easily by passing `-jaxpmodule` argument in `standalone.sh` (using this, my code picked the correct JAXP implementation as well) -

```
java -jar jboss-modules.jar -jaxpmodule "javax.xml.jaxp-provider"
```

But I'd like to do this using **jboss-deployment-structure.xml** and add an exclusion like this -

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <deployment>
    <exclusions>
        <module name="javax.api" />  // is the module name correct?
    </exclusions>   
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

But this isn't working, how can I fix this?

Comment: Shouldn't you exclude the javax.xml.bind.api or com.sun.xml.bind modules?

Comment: I am using `JAXP` since all i am doing is parsing an xml. AFAIK `JAXB` is used to bind XML documents to a java object model.

Comment: Also, via '-jaxpmodule' argument, jboss-modules.jar lets us specify the `JAXP` module implementation. There is no such argument available for any other `JBoss` module. Does this mean that it was intended to specify `JAXP` implementation via only command line?

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in your update, JBoss/Wildfly does ship its own JAXP implementation - Xalan (and Xerces). As such, it uses that implementation as it builds the classpath for your deployed application(s). 
You can override this behavior in your `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` file as follows:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>            
        <exclusions>            
            <module name="org.apache.xalan" />
            <module name="org.apache.xerces" /> 
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: While this will filter out the classes, it won't take care of registration of the included implementations via META-INF/services. These will still remain set according to those 2 excluded modules.

I wish there would be an easy way how to completely switch to the default JDK implementations and in a compatible way (with other JDKs where the classes may be in different packages etc).
Now you can either add your own META-INF/services settings which may break at other JDKs, or use system properties which are quite cumbersome (you need to set a bunch of them) and will affect the whole JVM.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to remove JARs from the Server's runtime.It is always advisable to exclude these JARs from your project at runtime.E.g. If you are using Maven for dependency management,then for this particular JAR in your pom.xml,you can just provide scope for this JAR as "provided".Provided scope indicates that this JAR will be used for compile time and at runtime it will be provided by runtime itself.

Comment: How is it possible to exclude a dependency specified by JBoss using maven?

Comment: Useless answer, he wants to avoid the old version provided by jboss.